# User-dependent packages/files in /lib

Tags: linux, package-management, users, configuration, libraries

I have setup a 2-seat computer. I start one X11 server using the computer's onboard graphics card (intel) and another in the dedicated one (nvidia).
Everything runs fine, except opengl. Currently, only the nvidia-seat has opengl due to conflicting files from nvidia and intel opengl packages in /lib.

**Is there any way to force one user to use libs from different a path?**

Every general /lib thing I found affects the whole system (ldconfig).
I've also considered FUSE, but I worry about general security and performance issues. chroot is only viable if I don't have to double and maintain all files. unionfs seemed right if it would allow for user-dependent overlays, but I never messed with unionfs and nothing I found suggests it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your programs are dynamically linked, then yes, by defining LD_LIBRARY_PATH for each session separately pointing to different directories with intel and nvidia shared libraries, and storing only system default libs in /lib.

Comment: I thought LD_LIBRARY_PATH was for link time only.    This should work, then. When I'm able to test this I'll mark as solved.

Comment: Your solution worked partially, ldd indicates libGL is loaded from path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but glxinfo still doesn't work.

Comment: My distro's libGL package (intel) has more files which are not in lib, and /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so is common in both packages. Changing xorg modules path doesn't work. Would this be a new question altogether, or should I edit this one? (Gave you an upvote anyway)

Comment: Ah, I forgot about Xorg guts! There must be a way to change that dynamically. Xorg -help gives me -showDefaultModulePath which shows the path up to /usr/lib/xorg/modules and -modulepath which probably can change that at runtime. You should check Xorg.log then each time you'll experiment with these. Note that I don't know how it's going today in modern distros, because I still use Xorg which can be configured with xorg.conf.

Comment: Or even use LD_PRELOAD trick and load your needed libglx.so before any libs will start to load. Combine LD_PRELOAD with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and you should get desired result.

Comment: And strace will help you to debug your troubles like loading from wrong place. You can see what libs are loading with something like `strace -f -v -s150 -eopen,access,stat,stat64 -E LD_PRELOAD={...} -E LD_LIBRARY_PATH={...}  Xorg {xorg_cmdline} 2>&1 | fgrep .so` (syscall names can vary between archs)

Comment: I can't run Xorg with strace, permission denied (probably because of sticky bit), and as root LD_LIBRARY_PATH seems to take no effect (security?), but strace shows that (when I run as user) it tries to load files from "/usr/lib/xorg/modules-carla" (the new modules path), and glxinfo loads the correct libraries (http://pastebin.com/J7wzSg8x).

Comment: There should not be any problems when running it as true root (id shows uid=0 gid=0). I am unaware of any restrictions on glibc systems though, I use musl system. The point is to run X server with modules and all libraries you need for particular GPU.

Comment: OK I think this might be too hard to achieve in unified file tree form. Can you create and debug chrooted environments? There should not be problems with two completely separate chrooted filesystems that just contain Xorg server and userspace driver parts inside. I did run such one when I used proprietary driver. But you'll need strace still, and it's generally harder to complete. If you want, I can post a complete guide for you as an answer.

Comment: Would the chrooted environment be just to test, or to be used as final solution? If it's the latter I fail to realize how to integrate it with the rest of the system.
In any case, it seems this would result in alternative solution, so I think another answear would be appropriate. I'm familiar with chroot basics, bind mounts, etc.. It's the integration with system and deduplication that kills me.
Thanks!

Comment: It will be persistent for Xorg servers you wish to run. For the rest, I answered in my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Next try is to use two separated chroot file trees with identical Xorg file trees inside, just enough for two different Xorg servers to run, and keep using LD_LIBRARY_PATH in userspace.

For Xorg to run, you need to put all Xorg related libraries and programs inside chroot. This can be done with automatic tools like debian chroot, or manually. Below is a very quick start how to do that manually (actually, it worked well for one musl system in not so distant past):

- Create separate chroot directory, for example /X11/nvidia (and /X11/intel).
- Put X11 binaries and libraries into it, reflecting old system's layout (that is, put Xorg into /X11/nvidia/usr/bin, libX*.so* into /X11/nvidia/usr/lib and glibc core libraries from /lib into /X11/nvidia/lib - they usually prefixed with version number, so it's easy to find which).
- Do not forget about directories on which X server depends, namely /usr/lib/X11 or /usr/lib/xorg. They contain modules and drivers for various kind of devices, and of course nvidia/intel driver parts.
- You probably will need items such as /X11/nvidia/bin/sh and /X11/nvidia/sbin/modprobe. Create necessary directories and put binaries from host there.
- You will also need /X11/nvidia/tmp, /X11/nvidia/var/lib/xkb and /X11/nvidia/var/log.
- At this point, you can copy your /X11/nvidia into /X11/intel.
- Do find and copy in appropriate places the libglx.so file, and maybe other driver parts.
- Bind mount /dev into each /X11/nvidia/dev and /X11/intel/dev (creating directories before), or you can try to copy device nodes by monitoring what exactly each device requires with strace tool later
- Bind mount /proc and /sys as well.
- If you have X11 configuration in /etc/X11, copy each configuration for each your device into each chroot /etc directory.

At this point chrooted X11 servers should be ready. But many distro specific things may break this, because they impose some other modern dependencies (maybe you will be required to copy and start some other daemons into your chroots).

Client configuration: just point your clients to different driver libraries with LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can even put clients into chroot (and this will not require much of file tree layout change even), but you will probably end up with mirroring your system twice.

Clients should connect normally even if X11 socket missing. This is because they use abstract name registered by X server when calling connect(), without requiring existing socket, and this can be seen in strace output. But if your system requires existing socket, you will need to bind mount /tmp as well.

As an alternative you will still be need to strace your Xorg servers hard, finding libraries that loading wrong and pointing to right places with LD_PRELOAD and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Strace **must work** as root (if you did sudo -i or logged in as root), if it does not, then this is certainly a bug.

Comment: Ah, that's what you meant by debug in chroot. I'll give it a shot, but this will take some time (maybe few days) since I'm not familiar with my distro's (Void Linux) bootstrapper, and seems the simpler to maintain in the future. Thank you again for your thoughts!